# Pipeline not substituting array object

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to change my logging url and api key for different environments. For this, I am using the Variables, in my Azure release pipeline. At the moment, I have the database connection string working well.

[image]

However, I am struggling to get the logging variables to work. Now,there is an array, and I bvelieve you reference an array as field.child.1.field (So, that would assign the 2nd array objets's field.

I have this:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],

    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "myUrl",
          "apiKey": "myApiKey"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am trying to substitute the serverUrl and apiKey.

In my pipeline lok, all I see is:

- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.1988119Z Compressed: 17363747
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.2942311Z Applying JSON variable substitution for **/*.json
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.3272676Z Applying JSON variable substitution for D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_8357506149\appsettings.json
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.3275828Z Substituting value on key: ConnectionString
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.3717239Z Applying JSON variable substitution for D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_8357506149\MyApp.WebAPI.deps.json
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.3819830Z Applying JSON variable substitution for D:\a_temp\temp_web_package_8357506149\MyApp.WebAPI.runtimeconfig.json
- 2021-03-15T01:24:13.3822015Z JSON variable substitution applied successfully.

It does the ConnectionString one well, but doesn't do the others. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand it correctly. Your fault is the uppercase letter "L" in `SeriLog.WriteTo.1.Args.apiKey`. It should be "Serilog.WriteTo.1.Args.apiKey". The mistake is in both variables `apiKey` and `serverUrl`.

Comment: You beautiful person! Case sensitivity. Arggh! Thank you! Solved.

Comment: @Craig oh, thank you :) Case sensitivity is a big "deal" in JSON. I spent many days troubleshooting because of it.